# Adjust selectInput to show the correct work shifts

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to tweak my `selectInput`. The idea is that if I select any day on Sunday, for example, Morning and Evening options will appear in `selectInput`. If I select any day on Tuesday, only Evening appears, because these are the options I have in my `df1` database.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3"),
    Days = c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday", "Sunday","Tuesday"),
    Openinghours = c("Morning","Evening", "Morning","Evening","Evening","Evening")
    ),row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 selectInput("hours", label = h5("Which work shift do you choose??"),choices = list("", ""), 
                                            selected = ""),
                                                          ),
                               mainPanel(
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(df1)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by using datarange but you can do something like this to get what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3"),
    Days = c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday", "Sunday","Tuesday"),
    Openinghours = c("Morning","Evening", "Morning","Evening","Evening","Evening")
  ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 selectInput("day", label = h5("Which day do you choose??"), choices = unique(df1$Days), 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 selectInput("hours", label = h5("Which work shift do you choose??"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = "")
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observe(
  updateSelectInput(session, "hours", choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == input$day, 3]))
  )  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

if you want to pick a date from a dropdown :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3"),
    Days = c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday", "Sunday","Tuesday"),
    Openinghours = c("Morning","Evening", "Morning","Evening","Evening","Evening")
  ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 dateInput("date", "Which day shift do you choose?"),
                                 selectInput("hours", label = h5("Which work shift do you choose??"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = "")
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observe({
    week_day <- wday(input$date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)

    updateSelectInput(session, "hours", choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day, 3]))
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @asaei, that's exactly what I want to do, but instead of having a `selectInput` on days, it's a `daterange`. That is, if I choose any Sunday day in the calendar, the Morning and Evening options appear.

Comment: you can use ```lubridate``` for that but better use ```datainput``` instead of  ```daterange```  if you not want to pick a day. I have updated the answer to include this